# Packet Captures saved in bin file format

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, bin

Does anyone know of a tool to open a packet capture saved as a .bin file? That or how to convert it to pcap or something wireshark can open.

I took a packet capture from a thin client and when I download it its a .bin file type. I have not been able to find out who to open it to view it.

Comment: The problem is that .bin is a generic file type - it could be any format. Can you post some more details?

Comment: @Dan the packet capture is from a wyse 5030 thin client

Comment: And what option did you use to acquire it? "Network capture to USB" should give you a pcap file according to this: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/854562/Dell-Wyse-Thinos-C10le.html?page=64 Though I confess to never having actually tried it myself. Your firmware OS may be different though - I'm not sure what exactly those run

Comment: @Dan yea this model does not have that option, it's just a web admin page with an option to start the capture then download it.

Comment: Is this definitely a network capture - some of them have a feature where you're capturing a video of the screen. Try opening your bin file in VLC...

Comment: @Dan nope VLC could not read it, didn't find video or audio

Comment: Does `capinfos` (https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/capinfos.html) recognize it?  Did you try asking Dell support what the format is?

Answer (score 1):

I had to create an account at the teradici website, their website just says its in binary format, but they do provide a script in python to convert it to a pcap. KB2484.

The script says i'm not allowed to post publicly so I wont do that. [Link](https://teradici.parature.com/ics/support/KBResult.asp)

Comment: It's too bad that the conversion process involves running the convert_to_pcap.py script, which utilizes an intermediate text file that is then run through text2pcap in order to save the data into a pcap file.  This isn't particularly efficient.  Ideally, Wireshark could be modified to be able to directly read the file without requiring any conversion at all, and you might consider opening a Wireshark bug report for this, but barring that, it would be much better if the conversion tool was able to directly generate a pcap file instead of using an intermediate step.  Can you post a capture file?

Comment: here it is [Example bin pcap](https://lift-allcompanyinc.box.com/s/zp9sx3ae94mf00xcn8ablo2rhvh18x9k)

Comment: I think it should be possible to modify the script to write pcap files directly.  The bin file format contains no global header, only a packet header of the following format (all multi-byte fields are little-endian):  
  
 - Hour: 1 byte  
 - Day: 1 byte  
 - Month: 1 byte  
 - Unused: 1 byte  
 - Milliseconds: 2 bytes  
 - Seconds: 1 byte  
 - Minutes: 1 byte  
 - Length: 4 bytes  
 - "Length" bytes of packet data follows  
  
If month is 0, assume June 1, 1999.  

To convert, use the libpcap format, documented here: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat